# how to retrieve the date via session variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, label

So here is the scenario:

**Page1.aspx:**

I created a read-only textbox, followed by a simple calendar.
On selecting the date, the long date appears in the textbox.

**Page1.aspx.cs:**

created a session and stored the date in it.

**Page2.aspx:**

Created a label field to house the date value.

**Page2.aspx.cs:**

now i want to rerieve the date value into the label.

**Problem1**: on selecting the date from the calendar, the page refreshes and then the data is reflected into the textbox

**Problem2**: can't convert and store the date values into the label.

Please help.

Comment: Why not use the query string to transport the date-value to the other page?

Comment: There are too many date fields from which i have to transport the dates to another page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataType variable=(Datatype)Session["SessionVariable"];
```

Retrieve like this by typecasting the session value to its appropriate type.

For Example:

```
Date variable=(Date)Session["date"];
```

Comment: error: cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Comment: can u write the statement what u have written

Comment: DateTime sd = (DateTime)Session["StartDate"];
i want to do something like this--lbl_start_date.Text = (DateTime)Session["StartDate"];

Comment: U can also access session value using  HttpContext.Current.Session["startDate"]

Comment: DateTime sd = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["StartDate"]);

Comment: but then can i directly apply it to a label?

Comment: here is the sequence of events:
tb_startdate.Text = cl1.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
 Session["StartDate"] = tb_startdate.Text.ToString();
            or 
            tb_startdate.Text = (DateTime)Session["startDate"];
on destination page
lbl_sdt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["StartDate"]);

please work around this situation

Comment: lbl_sdt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["StartDate"]);

Comment: it still shows the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.DateTime' to 'String'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand Problem1 correctly, but it seems that you would like the page to display the date in the textbox without reloading. In that case, take a look at jQuery UI's Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

As to Problem2, you probably can fix that by creating a new DateTime object with the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The other way around (from DateTime to string) can be done with the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: isn't there any other way? i'd rather not use jquery

Comment: Yes, but for sure you need to use Javascript for that. jQuery would make it much simpler to address the problem than using plain Javascript. Also, Datepicker is already there, and it's thoroughly tested.